# seprator is not visible in uitable view for dynamic height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ipad

I am designing an app in which i have used a table view.This table view uses a custom cell.I have given proportinal height to the table view.T

**tableview height constraints:**

```
equal height to mainview
multiplier:189:568
```

**Cell properties**

```
cell height:77
```

[image]

**Image constraints:**

[image]

**Label constraints**

[image]

**TextViewContsraints**

[image]

**bottom right label constraints**

[image]

**Code to make the row height dynamic**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:

    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        float percentage = (77.0 / 568.0);
        float height = self.view.frame.size.height * percentage;

        return (height>77.0)?height:77.0;
    }
```

**Issue screen**

[image]

Comment: reduce image size and try again.

Comment: i HAVE ALREADY REDUCE THE IMAGE SIZE

Comment: Are you calling `[super layoutSubviews]` in your custom cell implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Is the UITableViewCell in IB associated with a UITableViewCell subclass that overrides drawRect:? If so, make sure you are calling the super implementation, as that's what draws the line at the bottom. If you are overriding layoutSubviews make sure no views are obscuring the bottom of the cell.

In my case, i forgot to call [super layoutSubviews] after overriding the layoutSubviews method. Took me hoursto find the problem.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Increase custom cell size to 80-88 may be it solve your problem